# Checking two product Id (Subscription) in the app

Tags: android, in-app-billing, subscription, in-app-subscription

I have implemented In-App subscription in the app. As per my requirement, i need to change price for which i have to create new product and implement new id in the code. So is there any way to check the older subscription for status side by side along with new subscription status as well?